# Enable and Disabling a JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code and what I would like to do with it is to enable and disable the JavaScript code with a button.

So when I press the button the JavaScript code is enable, then press it again and it is disabled.

I don't want to Enable / Disable JavaScript itself. But just the code inbetween `<script></script>`

It would be controlled by a bool so, true / false.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to say. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do toggle the value of a hidden variable `onClick` of the `button`
and in the `<script>`, you can check the value of the hidden variable

For eg:

```
<input type='hidden' name='js_enabled' value='1' />
<button name='toggle_js' onClick='toggle()'>Toggle</button>

<script>
    function toggle() {
      if (document.getElementByName('js_enabled').val == 1) {
        document.getElementByName('js_enabled').val = 0
      } else {
        document.getElementByName('js_enabled').val = 1
      }
    }

    if (document.getElementByName('js_enabled').val == 1) {
      //your functions here
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set a global variable and check its value inside every function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.runScripts = true;

    function enableScripts() { window.runScripts = true; }
    function disableScripts() { window.runScripts = false; }

    function func_1() {
        if (window.runScripts) { /* run your code */ }
    }

    function func_2() {
        if (window.runScripts) { /* code for function 2 */ }
    }

    // ....
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be quite tedious?

Comment: I know, but what else can you do?